# $rootScope:infdig 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting when using event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm checking authentication in angular app, code given below
when I'm uncommenting event.preventDefault() given in code it's giving [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting error what's the problem in code pls suggest

```
    var app = angular.module('sss', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource', "ngStorage", "ngProgress", "ngCookies", 'angular-jwt', 'ngLodash','tagged.directives.infiniteScroll']);
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', "$httpProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($stateParams) {
        console.log("val check", $stateParams, window.location);
        window.location.href = "/undefined";

    });
    $stateProvider.state("jobs", {
        url: "/jobs",
        templateUrl: "views/dashboard.html",
        controller: "JobController as JobCtrl",
        resolve : {
            formInfo : ["AuthService",function (AuthService) {
                return AuthService.getFormInfo();
            }]
        }
    }).state("undefined", {
        url: "/undefined",
        templateUrl: "views/pagenotfound.html",
        bodyClass: "errors errors-404 errors-centered"
    }).state("login", {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "views/login.html",
        controller: "LoginController as LoginCtrl",
        resolve : {
            formInfo : ["AuthService",function (AuthService) {
                return AuthService.getFormInfo();
            }]
        }
    }).state("home",{
        url:"/home",
        resolve : {
          redirect:function($window)
          {
               $window.location.href = "/jobs"
          }
        }
    })
}]);
```

```
app.run(['$rootScope','$urlRouter', 'ngProgressFactory', '$state', '$compile', '$location', '$cookies', 'jwtHelper','AuthService', function ($rootScope,$urlRouter ,ngProgressFactory, $compile, $state, $location, $cookies, jwtHelper,AuthService) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
        $rootScope.progressbar = ngProgressFactory.createInstance();
        $rootScope.progressbar.start();
        $rootScope.location = $location;
    });

  var authPreventer =  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {

        var notCheckRoute = ["/undefined", "/signin", "/login"];
          //event.preventDefault();
          AuthService.checkPermission()
            .then(function(data) {

              console.log('if',$location.path(),data.active);

                if(data.active){

                    $location.path('/jobs'); 
                }else{
                    $urlRouter.sync();
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
            });
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        $rootScope.progressbar.complete();
        $rootScope.bodyClass = toState.bodyClass;
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (event) {
        //$state.go('undefined');
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Why do you need both `$locationChangeStart` and `$stateChangeStart`? What happens when you put all under `$stateChangeStart`?

Comment: if i put in $stateChangeStart and uncommented event.preventDefault(); page is not loading , if i comment event.preventDefault(); then page is loading but the problem is when user is not logged in and user directly goes to /jobs page then page is little bit loading then redirecting to login page ,but user shouldn't see jobs page somewhat , it will immediately redirect to login page

Comment: A resolve function needs a return. Seem to have some spaghetti logic going on here

Comment: I put return in resolve , pls ignore /home im not using tht

Comment: The more code there is to go through, the less likely people can find your problem. Streamline your example to use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When using the ui-router, avoid putting code in the `$locationChangeStart` block. This will cause conflicts with ui-router operation.

To prevent the jobs page from loading, check the authorization in the resolver for the state.  For more information, see [angularjs authentication using $locationChangeStart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810332/angularjs-authentication-using-locationchangestart/43824580#43824580).